# Mailbox database automatic activation

Tags: database, exchange-server, directed-acyclic-graphs

I am new to exchange server development. I want to know that how can my exchange server switch to a copy mailbox database in DAG if my provided mailbox database (at creation time) is not mounted.

Also what configurations I need to do so?

Answer (score 0):

If the mail DB is not mounted, the server couldn´t switch to it. The mail DB *must* be mounted otherwise it couldn´t be used. There will be also no replication between DAG mailDBs when they aren´t mounted.

However if the DAG is healthy which can be checked via:

- [Get-MailboxDatabaseCopyStatus](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd351258(v=exchg.160).aspx)
- [Test-ReplicationHealth](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb691314(v=exchg.160).aspx)

You can switch over the active mail DB from the dag member 01 to 02 via:

- [Move-ActiveMailboxDatabase](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd298068(v=exchg.160).aspx)